# Showing each Date as Column

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table A fields:

 - id
 - date
 - etc

Table B fields (contains detail items for each id in Table A):

 - id
 - idA (Table A id)
 - items
 - qty
```

I'm trying to showing each item's qty for a week, something like this.

```
RESULT:

 - items
 - qtydate1
 - qtydate2
 - qtydate3
 - SUM(qty)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? We need a bit more information. Also what have you tried SQL-wise?

Comment: Can you post a few example rows for each table and then an example of what your desired output is?

Comment: try something from your side ... If any struggle come here with question....  hope u r seeking cross tab qry

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close I think to what you're after? Room for improvement on the YEARWEEK() function to get back the date of that week's Sunday perhaps?

```
SELECT b.items, YEARWEEK(a.date) AS week, SUM(b.qty)
FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
        ON a.id=b.idA
GROUP BY b.items, YEARWEEK(a.date)
ORDER BY b.items, week
```